# Provide RSS for ALL views

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, feed, views

I would like to have RSS feeds for given tag **AND** specific view like this

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag=c++&sort=newest
https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag=boost&sort=active

Having ability to combine tags would be even better

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag=sqlite+sqlite3&sort=votes

And the last but not the least;
**How the feature which had 343 votes on UserVoice didn't get moved to meta?**

Answer (score 1):

implemented per:

[Any way to get an RSS feed of 'newest' tagged questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10140/any-way-to-get-an-rss-feed-of-newest-tagged-questions/25389#25389)

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I created a Yahoo pipe with this functionality for Newest view.

The pipe is called *StackOverflow - the newest questions by tags* and you can find it either on [my page](http://pipes.yahoo.com/piotrdobrogost) with yahoo pipes or directly [here](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=nG3mFehy3hGLNEDgz0ypaA).
Or you can skip all this and subscribe to your custom RSS feed **only** with the newest questions with given tags;
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?Age=**AGE**&Tags=**TAGLIST**&_id=nG3mFehy3hGLNEDgz0ypaA&_render=rss
where
AGE can be any of; 10 min ago, 3 days ago, one week ago etc.
TAGLIST can be any tag list [accepted](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags) by SO; python+or+django, windows+linux, c%2B%2B+boost etc.

Comment: warning, we aggressively block Yahoo Pipes.

Comment: @Jeff What's the reason for doing this?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23826/jeff-why-did-you-block-yahoo-pipes